# Generate Script and save data from database in SSMS 2015 for specific date

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I am trying to save the data script from SSMS 2015 so that I can run the script later and update another database. Have tried to do like

Select database--->Select Task--->Generate Script and so on

I am able to save script for all rows which is having around 20 million rows and I need only last month entries.
Please  guide me correct way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a `SELECT....INTO` query to create a table with just the data you want, use the Generate Script functionality on the new table, then drop the table?

Comment: guessing you meant to say you're not able to save the whole data. Also please don't use indian words, and instead of "data" you probably mean rows?

Comment: Hello James thanks for reply, here I am trying to say I can save the script for all the rows with the method I stated but I am not getting any option to save script for last month entries.